# Trouble using JavaScript for loop to populate an array with HTML divs

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to populate the contents of an array with the HTML from 5 different div elements using a loop.  I can't get the for loop to work correctly.  Any ideas?

The HTML:

```
<div id="person0">John</div>
<div id="person1">Kathleen</div>
<div id="person2">Cynthia</div>
<div id="person3">Eric</div>
<div id="person4">Jay</div>



<div style="width: 600px; margin: auto; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid gray; font-family: sans-serif;">
        <h1>The People</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
function pageLoaded(){

  var list = "<ul>";
  var myArray = new Array();

  for(i=0; i<6; i++){
    var person = "person";
    var personNumber = "" + i.toString();
    var divId = person.concat(personNumber);
    myArray[i] = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
    list +="<li>"+myArray[i]+"</li>";
  }


  list +="</ul>";

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=list;

}
```

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but have you looked into using jQuery?  It makes JavaScript development much easier and more elegant.

Comment: I've definitely thought about that but I'm trying to get better at JS functions so sort of doing this for practice :)

Comment: good for you on practicing core JS, best wishes with that.  Tossed together a page with your HTML and JavaScript, with some alerts, got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the `for` condition from `i<6` to `i<5`.

You were running the loop one too many times, which meant on the sixth iteration when you did:

```
myArray[i] = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
```

You were looking for an element with id of `"person5"`, so `getElementById()` returned `null` which gave the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

...which stopped your script from completing.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/awubeq/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! Wow--it's always some silly little mistake like that.  I always forget that arrays start with the index at 0.  This fixed it.

Comment: I have something like:
<div><span> </span></div>

When I use your code, and I use "alert" to show me the result, the result inside the div is the text + "<span> </<span>". 
How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 1):

You are looping thru more divs than you have. If you switch it to 4, it works.

```
for(i=0; i<5; i++){

or 

for(i=0; i<=4; i++){
```

Comment: That will skip the last item. Needs to be `<=4` or `<5`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution (plus some alerts):

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <script>

function pageLoaded()
{
  alert("called pageLoaded");
  var list = "<ul>";
  var myArray = new Array();

  for(i=0; i<5; i++){
    var person = "person";
    var personNumber = "" + i.toString();
    var divId = person.concat(personNumber);
    myArray[i] = document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML;
    alert("myArray[i]=" + myArray[i]);
    list +="<li>"+myArray[i]+"</li>";

  }


  list +="</ul>";

  alert(list);


  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=list;

}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="pageLoaded()">

<div id="person0">John</div>
<div id="person1">Kathleen</div>
<div id="person2">Cynthia</div>
<div id="person3">Eric</div>
<div id="person4">Jay</div>



<div style="width: 600px; margin: auto; padding: 15px; border: 1px solid gray; font-family: sans-serif;">
        <h1>The People</h1>
        <div id="result"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an iterator, you don't have to worry about knowing the size of the target of iteration.

```
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML =
Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll('[id^=person]'),
    function (prev, elem) {
       return prev + '<li>' + elem.innerHTML + '</li>';
}, '<ul>') + '</ul>';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/Avfjs/1/

Answer (score 0):

Since you are practicing, I just wanted to point out that you should reconsider the markup as this is not a case for using an `id` attribute but for a `class`. The `id` approach, though common, is incorrect and requires more code than necessary. Here is an example with better markup, which makes using javascript with it much more straightforward.

http://jsfiddle.net/3gpe8/